# How to use AIM to communicate with a Google Talk user?

Tags: google-talk, aim

How do I allow someone that uses the AIM desktop client to chat with someone else using the Google Talk desktop client? Both systems are Windows XP.  The trick is that I don't want to have them have to change clients.

Long ago I used Trillian... then Pidgin and now Meebo. But these are not solutions to the question. Also note that the Google client is not the web gadget.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This lifehacker article might help:

[Chat with AIM, MSN, Yahoo, and other contacts over Google Talk](http://lifehacker.com/289097/chat-with-aim-msn-yahoo-and-other-contacts-over-google-talk)

This requires on the Google Talk computer the free Jabber client Psi, but only for one time in order to set everything up. This works because Google Talk is a Jabber client.

Comment: Looks promising.  I'll give it a shot when I'm at that end of the connection.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I use Trillian which supports AIM, Yahoo, Jabber, ICQ, Google Talk, Skype, Twitter and more through one interface.

Comment: Thanks, but I mentioned that I have used Trillian and other multi-network clients but that 'these are not solutions to the question'.

Comment: trillian is much better than it was.