# How do I use an AIM/Windows Live/Yahoo! account to chat with Google Talk users?

Tags: instant-messaging, mobile-phone, chat, google-talk, aim

I just got a new phone with IM capability.  I'm too cheap to pay for a data plan, but I do have unlimited texts/IM.  However, all my friends use Google Talk, and this phone only supports AIM/Windows Live/Yahoo! accounts.

I know there are ways to use Jabber transports to talk to other networks using Google Talk (as pointed to in [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/86387/how-to-use-aim-to-communicate-with-a-google-talk-user)), but I'm basically looking for a way to go the other direction; I want to log into my AIM account and see my Google Talk buddies.  Any ideas?